# Paste a string to selected column names of a dataframe with dynamic number of columns

Tags: r

I have the dataframe below which will actually have a dynamic number of columns.I want to paste a string `"-actual"` from the second column name up to the last column name of the dataframe.

```
structure(list(month = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
"Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"), `2020` = c(NA, 5.26666666666667, 
-15.5806451612903, -41.4333333333333, -27.1290322580645, -15.7666666666667, 
-14.8709677419355, -14.9677419354839, -14.9333333333333, -15.7741935483871, 
-19.8666666666667, -19.741935483871), `2021` = c(-25.5806451612903, 
-23.4285714285714, -10.8387096774194, -8.3, -5.41935483870968, 
-3.53333333333333, -3.87096774193548, -4.67741935483871, -6.1, 
-5.54838709677419, -7.43333333333333, -6.7741935483871), `2022` = c(-18.9677419354839, 
-12.3571428571429, -10.4193548387097, -8.66666666666667, -6.06451612903226, 
-6.83333333333333, -8.64516129032258, -7.09677419354839, -8.73333333333333, 
-8.53333333333333, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Comment: Just use `paste` and assign `names(df1)[-1] <- paste0(names(df1)[-1], "_actual")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `dplyr::rename_with()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  rename_with(\(x) paste0(x, "-actual"), .cols = !month)
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
  month `2020-actual` `2021-actual` `2022-actual`
  <chr>         <dbl>         <dbl>         <dbl>
1 Jan           NA           -25.6         -19.0 
2 Feb            5.27        -23.4         -12.4 
3 Mar          -15.6         -10.8         -10.4 
4 Apr          -41.4          -8.3          -8.67
5 May          -27.1          -5.42         -6.06
6 Jun          -15.8          -3.53         -6.83
7 Jul          -14.9          -3.87         -8.65
8 Aug          -15.0          -4.68         -7.10
9 Sep          -14.9          -6.1          -8.73
10 Oct          -15.8          -5.55         -8.53
11 Nov          -19.9          -7.43         NA   
12 Dec          -19.7          -6.77         NA
```

NB, since the `cols` argument uses the [tidyselect DSL](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/language.html), you can get the same result using:

- `!month` (all columns besides `"month"`),
- `!1` (all but the first column),
- `` `2020`:`2022` `` (all columns from `"2020"` through `"2022"`),
- `matches("^\\d+$")` (all columns consisting of digits only),
- `where(is.numeric)` (all columns with numeric values),
- etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use the setNames() function and paste() inside the function :

```
df<-setNames(df, c(names(df)[1], paste(names(df)[-1], "_actual", sep = "")))
df<-as.data.frame(df)
df
   month 2020_actual 2021_actual 2022_actual
1    Jan          NA  -25.580645  -18.967742
2    Feb    5.266667  -23.428571  -12.357143
3    Mar  -15.580645  -10.838710  -10.419355
4    Apr  -41.433333   -8.300000   -8.666667
5    May  -27.129032   -5.419355   -6.064516
6    Jun  -15.766667   -3.533333   -6.833333
7    Jul  -14.870968   -3.870968   -8.645161
8    Aug  -14.967742   -4.677419   -7.096774
9    Sep  -14.933333   -6.100000   -8.733333
10   Oct  -15.774194   -5.548387   -8.533333
11   Nov  -19.866667   -7.433333          NA
12   Dec  -19.741935   -6.774194          NA
```